# Java Android, listing multiple stored values in settext

Tags: java, android

I have a blank text field which I'm trying to use settext on after a button click, so I can change the blank text field to the text in the stored variables.

The variables are two ints which I've converted to string and I'm trying to do the following:

```
blankText.setText("" + var1);
```

currently works but when I try to add the other variable in the same field I'm not sure how to go about it?

For example I tried to do: `blankText.setText("" + var1, var2)` which throws an error. I want them listed side by side in the same text field. is this possible?

Comment: `blankText.setText("" + var1+var2)` ??

Answer (score 0):

To combine Strings, use `+`:

```
blankText.setText(var1 + var2);
```

Answer (score 0):

blankText.setText(var1 + " " + var2);

Answer (score 0):

blankText.setText("" + var1 + "  " + var2);
if you want to space your variables

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to **add** or **append** the text in already written textview then use

```
blankText.append(""+var2);
```

if you want to write two variables in textview at the same time then use the concatination symbol

```
 blankText.setText(" " + var1 + " " + var2); // also will remove the previous written text
```